# how to insert values from two tables with value in one table is equal to value in the other?

Tags: php, mysql

here i have two tables pro_zone_m and temp_const and i am inserting values into third table pro_m where i will be inserting zone from temp_const, and i need to get value of zone_id of corresponding zone from pro_zone_m.
i tried but could'nt able to come up with solution.

```
$uisq = "SELECT * FROM pro_zone_m";
$ytu = mysql_query($uisq);
$mnm = mysql_fetch_array($ytu);
extract($mnm);


$wqr = "SELECT * FROM temp_const";
$wqe = mysql_query($wqr);
while($wqe1 = mysql_fetch_array($wqe))
{
extract($wqe1);


$zxc = "INSERT INTO pro_m set custid='$custid', firstname='$firstname',     lastname='$lastname', country='$country', 
city='$city', state='$state', zone='$zone', adresstype='$address_type',     address1='$address1', address2='$address2',category='$category', 
focus='$focus', assignto='$assign_to', division='$division',     product='$product', grade='$grade', potential='$potential',     designtn='$designation',
mobile='$mobile', primphone='$primary_phone', primemail='$primary_email',
exhibition = '$exhibition',  zonea_id = '$zoneid' WHERE zone = '$code' ";

$zxc1 = mysql_query($zxc);
```

Comment: You are mixing `insert into` and `update`.

Comment: if its insert into you don't need where

Comment: if it insert or update use insert on duplicate key update

Answer (score 0):

Update your insert query like this:(assuming zonea_id will store zone_id from temp_const table.

$zxc = "INSERT INTO pro_m set custid='$custid', firstname='$firstname',     lastname='$lastname', country='$country', 
city='$city', state='$state', zone='$zone', adresstype='$address_type',     address1='$address1', address2='$address2',category='$category', 
focus='$focus', assignto='$assign_to', division='$division',     product='$product', grade='$grade', potential='$potential',     designtn='$designation',
mobile='$mobile', primphone='$primary_phone', primemail='$primary_email',
exhibition = '$exhibition',  **zonea_id = (SELECT zone_id FROM temp_const where  zone = '$code')** ";